# What chemicals will kill P1 Phage but not E. coli?

Tags: biochemistry, bacteriology, virology, organic-chemistry

I'm working with *E. coli* and P1 Phage. I'm wondering if there is some chemical agent that will kill or disable P1 but leave *E. coli* untouched? It is not enough to just prevent infection. It must destroy the Phage.

Comment: No such chemical exists. Otherwise we would use it whenever we have a phage breakout in labs across the world.